# Shoulda on Rails - should render_with_layout deferred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shoulda

I would appreciate if someone could help/explain the following please.

I am trying to test a controller with shoulda to see if a correct layout is used.

The method should_render_with_layout throws a NoMethodError whilst should render_with_layout passes but says the function is deferred.

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks
Matt

Comment: Which version of shoulda are you using? Can you post your test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and thanks to tsdbrown for your response. I am running shoulda 2.10.2. I have manage to resolve the problem. I had not initiated a get request, but after adding get request to setup the below test is now passing. Thanks for help.

```
 context "getting index" do
   setup do
     get :index
   end

   should_respond_with :success
   should_render_with_layout :admin
   should_render_template :index
   should_assign_to :venue, :class => Venue
   should_not_set_the_flash
 end
```